# Deleting my messages in a server using bulkDelete (discord.js)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am new to discord.js but learned that I can delete my messages using bulkDelete and it will delete them all, even if they are older than 2 weeks. I clear my messages in a server I moderate manually once a month and needless to say it takes forever. I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me make a command that will do this automatically whenever I call it?

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a recursive function that checks if there are messages in the channel (100 max every time): if there are no messages it stops otherwise it deletes them and restarts.

```js
function clean(channel, limit = 100) {
  return channel.fetchMessages({limit}).then(async collected => {
    let mine = collected.filter(m => m.author.id == 'your_id_here'); // this gets only your messages
    if (mine.size > 0) {
      await channel.bulkDelete(mine, true);
      clean(channel);
    } else channel.send("The channel is now empty!").delete(5000); // this message is deleted after 5 s
  });
}
```

You can adapt this idea to your existing command parser or, if you don't know how to implement this, try:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.author.bot || msg.author != YOU) return; 
  // with YOU i mean your User object, to check permissions

  let command = 'clean', // the name of your command
    args = msg.content.split(' ');
  if (args[0].toLowerCase() == command) 
    clean(msg.channel, !isNaN(args[1]) ? args[1] : undefined); //<-- THIS is how to use the function
  // used a ternary operator to check if the other arg is a number
});
```

This is just a **very** basic implementation, there are a lot of better ways to detect commands.

Comment: This deletes all the messages, I was simply wanting it to search for my own and delete them, even if they're older than 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a way to filter messages.
You can fetch messages and then check for each message if its yours

```
await message.channel.fetchMessages({
  limit: 100
}).then((msgCollection) => {
  msgCollection.forEach((msg) => {
    if(msg.author.id == message.author.id) {
      msg.delete();
    }
  })
});
```